# Imagick convert image from external URL

Tags: php, imagick

I'm trying to copy an image from external URL, please help.

```
convert -quality 80 https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/46/70/6c/46706c1cbf3e505a2b4abf99eee0fe02.jpg /home/user/public_html/files/test.jpg
```

SSH error output:

```
convert: not authorized `//s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/46/70/6c/46706c1cbf3e505a2b4abf99eee0fe02.jpg' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/453.
convert: missing an image filename `/home/user/public_html/files/test.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3015.
```